# Rails 4.1: Spacing Issues when using HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

[image]First time HAML wth Ruby on Rails  , I want to align the average no of comments with the months. So the first one aligns but not the rest.

[image: screenshot of table so far]

monthly.stats.html.haml

```html
.row
  .col-md-3
    Month
  .col-md-9
    - 6.times.reverse_each do |i|
      %th= i.month.ago.strftime('%b %y')
      %tr
        - 6.times do
          %td &nbsp;


  .col-md-3
    Av. No of Comments
  .col-md-9
    - 6.times.reverse_each do |i|
      %tr #{@monitor.average_number_of_comments(i.months.ago, Time.now)}
      %tr
        - 6.times do
          %td &nbsp;
```

I am using

```
%tr
  - 6.times do
    %td &nbsp;
```

for spaces but this is not spacing correctly

Comment: Why are you even using `&nbsp`, at all? If you are just trying to space out the columns, why not use something like the [td width atribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp)?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables explains Bootstrap's table styles

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a table?

```html
.row
  %table.table-responsive
    %tr
      %th
        Month
      - 6.times.reverse_each do |i|
        %th= i.month.ago.strftime('%b %y')
    %tr
      %td
        Av. No of Comments
      - 6.times.reverse_each do |i|
        %td #{@monitor.average_number_of_comments(i.months.ago, Time.now)}
```

Just pay attention to the indentation. The loops should be indented in the same level as `%th` and `%td`. This way you will not need any hacks like `&nbsp;`. You can also avoid using tables altogether and just fully use the bootstrap grid system.